# How to write RegEx for URL

Tags: regex

I need to check URL. This examples must be true:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://stackoverflow.com
```

But this must not:

```
http:/www.stackoverflow
```

I tried to achieve it with RegEx:

```
http://(www\.)?.+\..+
```

But it is not working. All examples are true. This regex don't pay attention on `(www\.)` part.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're forgetting about `https:`.  Also, `http://www.com` is a valid URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: this regex works fine for the given examples, BUT you should escape the forward slashes

Comment: Please search thoroughly before asking questions.

Comment: Just to note, sites like http://www.gl and http://www.com DO exist.. and since TLDs can be up to 63 characters (24 is the longest I've heard of), URL matching has gotten a lot harder. Or you can take the legitimate path of ignoring the few scenarios of ignoring `www` domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?\S+\.\S+`

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the forward slashes:

```
http:\/\/(www\.)?.+\..+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `http:\/\/(www.)?.+\..+[a-z]`

Or if you also want to allow https: `http(s)?:\/\/(www.)?.+\..+[a-z]`